# Replacing NaN values in python with regards to a condition concerning another column

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, nan, economics

Good evening everyone!

I have a problem with NaN values in python with pandas.
I am working on database with information on different countries. **I cannot get rid** of all of my NaN values altogether or I would lose too much data.

I wish to replace the NaN values based on some condition.

[The dataframe I am working on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWQ1R.png)

What I would like is to create a new column that would take the existing values of a column (Here: OECDSTInterbkRate) and replace all its NaN values based on a specific condition.

For example, I want to replace the NaN corresponding to Australia with the moving average of the values I already have for Australia.

Same thing for every other country for which I am missing values (Replace NaN observations in this column for France by the moving average of the values I already have for France, etc.).

What piece of code do you think I could use?

Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: Please do not provide links to data sets or code which are not text based. That is very unhelpful. Also, try to provide a minimal set of code to reproduce the problem you are having. In this case a short pandas dataframe with the NaN's, created in code that is easily reproducable. Re-creating your work is not something people are going to spend time on.

Comment: Sure, I will try to update my question then, but being a beginner with python, I am not sure I know how to do that. I will try anyway, thank you for the feedback !

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like this `df.fillna(df.mean(), inplace=True)`
Replace `df.mean()` with your mean values.

Comment: I see, thank you very much ! But this would lead to replacing the nan by the mean of the whole column, I guess.. How can I couple that with the condition : "if country = Australia, then mean(australian values)?

Comment: Replace df.mean() with df.['Australia'].mean Try to upload actual dataset values/link for it and not images.